# How to avoid Compile Error: Object Required in this VBA code?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, debugging, compiler-errors

I am trying to create a running counter using x every time the string "YES" appears in column F. The code I'm trying to fix is searching for the string using the .Find and .FindNext functions, with if statements used to stop the loop or function when a search returns to the same "YES" string.

For some reason, the compile error "object required" keeps appearing even though I believe all objects are called and have appropriate object qualifiers.

I kept trying to change objects to different variables and vice versa. As well as trying to change the code's formatting. None seems to work.

```
Function Refill()
Dim x As Variant
Dim rg As Range
Dim search As Object
Dim search1 As Object
Dim search2 As Object
   
Set x = 0
Set Refill = 0
Set rg = Range("F:F")
Set search = rg.Find("YES")

If Not search Is Nothing Then
    x = 1
    Refill = x
    Set search1 = rg.FindNext(search)
    MsgBox (search1.Row)
    If search1.Row = search.Row Then Exit Function
    
    Do
    If Not search1 Is Nothing Then
        x = x + 1
        Refill = x
        Set search2 = rg.FindNext(search1)
        If search2.Row = search1.Row Then Exit Do
    End If
    Loop  
End If
End Function
```

Comment: Please do not post images of code, we can't cut and paste it into our Excel.  Please use the code tags and provide the actual code in the question.

Comment: You're over-using `Set` - that's only required for Object types, which `x` is not.  Likewise you use `Set Refill = 0` and then later `Refill = x`   If you only want to count how many "Yes" there are then `application.countif([F:F],"YES")` will do that

Answer (score 1):

This is the general pattern for using Find/FindNext in a loop:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    
    Dim rg As Range, f As Range, addr As String, x As Long
    
    Set rg = ActiveSheet.Range("F:F") 'be explicit about which worksheet
    'Provide all important arguments for the first Find(),
    ' in case a previous call set something you *don't* want
    Set f = rg.Find("YES", after:=rg.Cells(rg.Cells.CountLarge), lookat:=xlWhole, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
    
    If Not f Is Nothing Then                  'got a match?
        addr = f.Address                      'remember the location
        Do
            x = x + 1                         '...or do something with `f`
            
            Set f = rg.FindNext(f)            'any more matches?
            If f Is Nothing Then Exit Do      'no more matches
            If f.Address = addr Then Exit Do  '...or we looped back around
        Loop
    End If
    
    Debug.Print x
    
End Sub
```

Comment: You said Set is for object types, but I guess you also need it for setting the range and .Find function?

Comment: `Range` is a type of object, and `Find()` returns a `Range` object (or `Nothing` if there's no match)